# Scroll gridview rows at different speed

Tags: gridview, scroll, winrt-xaml

I want to create a gridview for winrt with different speed of scrolling for each row, but i don't know how to do that, if someone can help me.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to possibly hook in to the `GridView`'s `ManipulationDelta` event and affect the `GridView`'s child `ScrollViewer` (which you can retrieve by parsing the Visual Tree) by a factor of the `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs.Delta.Translation.X` (the X-translation of the manipulation). I don't know at all how smooth that would be, and it may be jarring considering the intended use of the touch input scrolling is to have the same point be under your finger at all times. One thing you may consider is using a Semantic Zoom for faster list traversal.

Answer (score 0):

[xamlplayground.org](http://www.xamlplayground.org/post/2012/05/19/Metro-Implement-a-parallactic-scrolling-for-your-GridView.aspx) has an example of what you want to do. It shows how to display a grid in a parallactic way. It is written for scrollviewer but article says this method can be applied to gridview and listview as well.

Here is the code:

```
<Grid>
       <Image x:Name="backImage" Margin="0,0,0,30" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                Source="/Assets/parallax_people.png" Width="2250" Height="200" Opacity="0.5" />

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="hScroll" 
                      Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Margin="0">
            <!-- insert your content here -->
        </ScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void hScroll_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var delta = (this.hScroll.HorizontalOffset / this.hScroll.ScrollableWidth) * (backImage.ActualWidth - this.hScroll.ViewportWidth);
        this.backImage.Margin = new Thickness(-delta, 0, 0, 30);
    }
```

You can randomize speed of scrolling if you want to have different speed on every row.

Comment: My need is more complex than parallatic scroll, I need a gridview with multiple rows, and each row scroll at a different speed to it's bottom row.

Comment: Is there any example of it?

Comment: Here [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uorJfwpTzoI] a demo with columns for IOS, I am trying to do the same for rows and the number of rows is variable.